# Playing a local file with Deezer player

Tags: android, deezer

Does the Deezer SDK offer the posibility to play local files on the device using the player?

If they do, is there a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Android and iOS SDKs play only tracks from Deezer's catalog, and are not meant to be used to play local files.

Comment: Thanks. Is this going to be supported in the future for Android? I wanted to try playing a local track to see if my platform has any problems locally.

Comment: You can play a local track using Android's MediaPlayer. Adding this feature inside Deezer's SDK is a little bit out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

But the JS SDK can do this with the method DZ.player.playExternalTracks(), the documentation is here: http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/loadtracks